# why does npm gives me warning when i try to install jquery-csv library using VS in ubuntu

Tags: visual-studio, ubuntu, github, package

I'm trying to install jquery-csv library
with visual studio in ubuntu for the first time

the [instruction](https://github.com/typeiii/jquery-csv/blob/master/README.md) says that to install package I should run:

```
npm i jquery-csv
```

however whenever I tried it npm warns me that it can't find `package.son`:

[image]

is this something i'm expected to see in a normal package installation?

if not, please help me with some instructions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're getting suggests you aren't using a Node.js project and don't have a `package.json` file.

If this is an existing browser-based project and you want to add the library, you can download `jquery.csv.min.js` from here: https://github.com/typeiii/jquery-csv/tree/master/src , and add a client-side (browser) reference in your HTML file as shown on the readme:

```
<script src="jquery.csv.min.js"></script>
```

If you're working on a new Node.js project, the first step is to run `npm init`, see [npm init - create a package.json file](https://preview-docs.npmjs.com/cli-commands/npm-init)